# sshpass command to run a shell script with input parameter

Tags: perl, ssh

I am using the following command in a perl script to run a shell script with input parameter that resides in a particular folder of a different server.

```
system('sshpass -p password ssh user@hostname "cd /folder1/fol2; ./test.sh $param1 $param2;"');
```

But it seems that the input parameter is not getting considered. Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: Variables do not interpolate within single quotes.

Comment: Thanks mate! I have finally used another shell script to do the ssh and called the same from my perl with system command and that worked!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting by hand is tricky, let perl do it for you:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('user@hostname', password => $password);
$ssh->system('cd', '/forlder1/fol2', \\'&&', './test.sh', $param1, $param2)
    or $ssh->die_on_error("Command failed");
```

Comment: I don't have privilege to install the package. But finally able to achieve the same by calling another shell script.